# StringContainsQ, but anywhere in order

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, permutation

I am trying to find a string within a string, but "anywhere", so long as it is in the right order.

For example

```
StringContainsQ["aabbc","ac"]
```

returns

> False

but I want `True`, since `ac` does in fact occur interleaved as position 1 and then position 5 in `aabbc`, as well as at position 2 and then position 5.

Anywhere, but in the right order. So

For example

```
NewStringContainsQFunction["aabbc","ba"]
```

should return.

> False

Is there a nice way to do this, apart from searching letter by letter, until the string is built?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
StringMatchQ["aabbc", "*a*c*"]
```

> True

```
StringMatchQ["aabbc", "*b*a*"]
```

> False

You can also use [`LongestCommonSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LongestCommonSequence.html) to construct a function

```
ClearAll[strngCntnsQ]
strngCntnsQ = LongestCommonSequence[##] == #2 &;

strngCntnsQ["aabbc", "ac"]
```

> True

```
strngCntnsQ["aabbc", "ba"]
```

> False

Comment: The second function is by far the best answer on here, since it immediately generalizes to longer second strings without needing to tweak it with `*`s etc.

Comment: @GregMartin That's true, but it's also far slower than a simple string pattern for non-trivial amounts of data. If you need efficiency, regular expressions or string patterns are much better.

Comment: @GregMartin `StringRiffle[Characters@"whatever", {"*", "*", ""}]`

Answer (score 14):

Is this what you need?

```
StringContainsQ["aabbc","a" ~~ ___ ~~ "c"]
```

> True

The following documentation pages should help you get going with string patterns in Wolfram Language:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringPatterns.html
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatternsOverview.html

**edit**
Here is a function that generalizes this idea to strings of arbitrary length:

```
NewStringContainsQFunction[str1_String, str2_String] := 
  StringContainsQ[
    str1,
    StringExpression @@ Riffle[Characters[str2], ___]
  ]

NewStringContainsQFunction["aabbc", "ac"]
NewStringContainsQFunction["aabbc", "ba"]
NewStringContainsQFunction["aadbebfc", "abc"]
```

> True
>
> False
>
> True

Answer (score 5):

```
StringContainsQ["aaabc", RegularExpression["a.*c"]]
```

> True